# Remove and Add Image to Reduce Page Lag

Tags: javascript, image, cesiumjs

I have a website where I am cycling through a bunch of images on a 3D globe.  I've come to notice that the more images that the user cycles through than the more lag the website gets.

I found out that it's due to each image being placed on top of the old one, just stacking one on top of the other.

Is there a way in javascript to remove an image and replace it without any noticable flicker.

here's the code that changes the image src

```
    function loadCesium()
    {
        //Cesium Active Window

        layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider({
            url : 'surfaceTempHeatMaps/'.concat(name),
            rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
        }));
        document.getElementById('changeable').src = 'colorbar/colorbar.png';
    }
```

it's in both the url part of layers and the colorbar.png

Comment: This code looks like it will stack up a bunch of globe images, but replace (not stack) a DOM image.  Which image are you asking about?  The globe image stacking can be fixed by saving the return value from `addImageryProvider` and then calling [`layers.remove`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ImageryLayerCollection.html#remove).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample that shows adding and removing a layer. This is on a two second interval.

The key here is, as emackey pointed out in the comments, saving the result from  returned from `addImageryProvider` and passing that to `remove`.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var layer;

setInterval(function() {
    if (layer) {
        viewer.imageryLayers.remove(layer);
        layer = null;
    } else {
        layer = viewer.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider({
            url : '../images/Cesium_Logo_Color.jpg',
            rectangle : Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
        }));
    }
}, 2000);
```

Live demo sandcastle: http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=b4eb1186ff9d580f1146493c1d15b984